# php multiple values in curly brackets

Tags: php, html

In php with html im using this code

```
 $data = $this->_item->getParams();
```

and i get as result multiple values in this format:

```
{ "metadata.title": "", "metadata.description": "", "metadata.keywords": "", "metadata.robots": "", "metadata.author": "", "config.enable_comments": "1", "config.primary_category": "2" }
```

But i need to get to these values by one and my the name.. for example i need to echo just "metadata.description" value..

i try all of this but none of that works..

```
echo $data('metadata.description');
echo $data->metadata.description;
echo $this->data('metadata.description');
```

whats the correct syntax here? 
thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like JSON. You'll need to [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first.

Either of these will work, depends on your preference of accessing the data:

```
$decoded = json_decode($data);
echo $decoded->{'metadata.description'};
```

or

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
echo $decoded['metadata.description'];
```